# How can i get the hole response when load a page

Tags: puppeteer

when I use `page.todo('https://www.alipay.com/'` and listen to the response event use `page.on('response', res => {console.log(res)})` there's no response.

But in fact there is a few http request when loading the page like this:
[info from chrome devTool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERMY1.png)

How should I get these request & response ?

I noticed that some of the pic request in the screenshot are in the CSS style code like `background-image`, are these request can't listen under the event 'response' ?

Here's my code:

```
'use strict';
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const devices = require('puppeteer/DeviceDescriptors');

const iPhone = devices['iPhone 6'];

(async () => {
  const browser = await initBrowser();
  const page = await openPage(browser, 'https://www.alipay.com');
  page.on('response', res => {
    console.log('response: ', res);
  });
  return browser.close();
})();

async function initBrowser() {
  return await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
}

async function openPage(browser, url) {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  try {
    await page.emulate(iPhone);
    await page.goto(url);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    page.close();
    return null;
  }
  return page;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the page requests, you have to set `page.setRequestInterception` to `true`.

Then on `request` event, every request will be intercepted and can be blocked or continued.

```
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on('request', interceptedRequest => {
    console.log(interceptedRequest.url()); // print out the request url
    interceptedRequest.continue(); // don't block the request
  });
  await page.goto('https://example.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is not listening for responses until after it navigates to the url, `page.on('request', res => console.log(res));` should be set before it navigates to the url.

```
const page = await browser.newPage();
page.on('request', res => console.log(res));
page = await openPage(page, url); // <-- pass in page here instead of browser
                                  // because page is now defined
```

If the code posted above has no omissions then it also does not have time to see the request before the browser closes.
`await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'load'});`

Or if there are other requests that conclude after the load event is fired you'll need to find another way to wait for the responses.